# Array to string conversion when using routeNotificationForDatabase

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-spark

I've wrote a custom model without any relations to the database that uses the `Notifiable` trait. To support Database notifications I've added the method `routeNotificationForDatabase()` to this class as follows:

```
public function routeNotificationForDatabase()
{
    return new Notification();
}
```

However, this results into the following error. So obviously i'm doing something wrong. Could anybody point me in the right direction for this?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `data`, `read_at`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (783ee870-cd52-4a2e-bdeb-fd89ca2aee11, App\Notifications\SystemMessage, *WARNING!* example.com is currently down., , 2018-04-28 18:53:35, 2018-04-28 18:53:35))

Stack Trace:

> 1   ErrorException::("Array to string conversion")
>         /Users/xxx/sites/xxx/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php : 101
>
> 2   PDOStatement::bindValue(["*WARNING!* example.com is currently down."])
>         /Users/xxx/sites/xxx/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php : 101

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Solved this by using the `toSpark()` channel for notifications instead of `toDatabase()`. I didn't realize that spark has a slightly different notifications model.

Comment: You are trying to call vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Notifications\Notification.php method?

Comment: @outman Thank you for your reply. I found out that spark has a slightly different set-up in their notifications model. So instead of using `toDatabase()` i have now turned to `toSpark()` which does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by using the `toSpark()` channel for notifications instead of `toDatabase()`. I didn't realize that spark has a slightly different notifications model.